# Simple best practices for ASP.NET models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want my View to be as follows:

```
@model MyProgram.Models.DocumentList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

@foreach (MyProgram.Models.Document doc in Model.GetDocs())
{
    <p>doc.Content</p>
}
```

This leads me to believe I need a Model that contains a list of another Model. So in a project containing nothing but this I would have:

```
/Model/DocumentList.cs
/Model/Document.cs
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Comment: Paul Aldred-Bann has given a correct example.

Comment: As far as my affair with MVC goes, One thing that I made out is, there should not be any kind of validations on your models, like `[Required]` attributes or infact any attribute. All the validations should be made on the ViewModel properties and not on Model properties. I believe all the answers also remain valid.This is in regard to the `simple best practices`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [View Models](http://sampathloku.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html) that way you can pass as many models to your view as it needs.  I also use view models to handle the validation of POSTs etc.  So in your case you can do something like:

**Your View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public DocumentList DocList { get; set; }
    // You could use your DocumentList object here, or if you
    // don't want to, just pass a List<T> of Document
    public List<Document> DocList { get; set; }
}
```

**Your View**

```
@model MyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.PageTitle;
}

@foreach (var doc in Model.DocList)
{
    <p>doc.Content</p>
}
```

There's MUCH more to MVC than this though, such as [Display and Editor Templates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/672591/Exploring-Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASP-NET) so I'd have a look online for some good tutorials that cover the MVC essentials.

**Edit**

To be fair, having read this back you're already *kind of* following this principle it's just that `DocumentList` is your view model (and you don't really need a `GetDocs` method, just have a collection property, unless you're performing logic on the collection before returning that is).

Hopefully this answer helps clarify a few things for you though?

Comment: This is a real best practices . Cheer's +1 and also the OP practice is best than other answers

Comment: Yes, this appears to be what I am looking for. Thankyou for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your needs. If you only have need a document model list in you view, I'd go only with a `Document` model and changing the passed view model to:

```
@model List<MyProgram.Models.Document>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

@foreach (MyProgram.Models.Document doc in Model)
{
    <p>doc.Content</p>
}
```

But if you need more properties or methods in your view, than I'd go with a view model containing a `List<MyProgram.Models.Document>` and the other properties.

```
@model DocumentsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

@foreach (MyProgram.Models.Document doc in Model.DocumentList)
{
    <p>doc.Content</p>
}
```

Model:

```
public class DocumentsViewModel
{
    public List<MyProgram.Models.Document> DocumentList {get; set;}

    ... other properties
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in assuming you need 2 model classes for that.
I would use a List property though so your code would look like :

```
@foreach (var doc in Model.Docs)
```

Also : 
Standard mvc creates a model folder for every controller.
So by default an mvc project looks like

```
root
  Controllers
    YourFirstController
  Views
    YourFirst
      Index
  Models
    YourFirst
      DocumentList
      Document
```

*update :
If you only want a list of items you can also pass a List to your model like this :

```
@model List<MyProgram.Models.Document>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

@foreach (var doc in Model)
{
    <p>doc.Content</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical concept employed in such cases. That is called ViewModel. A view model class can contain several model objects and other properties depending on the view. The ViewModel should have all the data that is required for a View. So In your case create a ViewModel named DocumentViewModel and create objects of two other models.

Hope this helps.